# How to hide the $_GET parameters using htacess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to hide the values of $_GET parameters in the url in the specific page only. The value of $_GET parameters is dynamically created.

Current url:

```
http://example.com/page/info/?name=Barbara&birth=1978-05-07
```

I want is:

```
http://example.com/page/info/
```

I tried to hide the $_GET parameters in the url using this htaccess  but it's not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+|)/?$ index.php?name=$1&birth=$2 [QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Make the method a post? I'm not exactly sure if what your asking can me completed.

Comment: If you remove those parameters, they're gone. No RewriteRule can pull them back out of thin air. -- So the question becomes: what's the purpose of this endeavour?

Comment: @mario, i want to hide/remove that values of get parameters in the url, so the user can't see that (for security purposes)

Comment: Obfuscating things out of sight is not commonly believed to be a security feature.

Comment: yes i know, but i want is to hide those values

Comment: Why doesn't sending it as a `POST` work?

Comment: `POST` is not working if the page will redirect after submit the form (in my side)

Comment: You can send a `POST` server side. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24004081/4333555

Comment: I will try that, but for now I want to know how to hide the get values in url for the meantime

Comment: You don't, if it's not there it's not `GET`. The only reason (I see) to use `GET` is for the user to know the address.

Comment: but i saw some question on how to hide the values, i tried them but it's not working in my side

Comment: @mario session is not working in wordpress without using plugin according to the articles that i've read

Comment: Your question seems to be based on a lot of wrong assumptions.